# How to prove there is no bijection between a finite set a proper subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I am reading Hrbacek-Jech's Introduction to Set Theory (3ed), and in chapter 4, section 2, which deals with finite sets, they define the following:

(Remember: in set theory, $n$ is a natural number iff $n = \{0, 1, \dots, n-1 \}$)

**Definition:** A set $X$ is finite if there is a bijection between $X$ and a natural number $n$; in such case we define the cardinal number of $X$ to be $\lvert X \rvert = n$. Moreover, a set is said to be infinite if it is not finite.

Then comes the first result of the section:

**Theorem:** If $n$ is a natural number, then there is no bijection between $n$ and a proper subset $X \subset n$.

Immediately after they prove $\mathbb{N}$ is an infinte set using the stronger result:

**Theorem:** If $X$ is a finite set, then there is no bijection between $X$ and a proper subset $Y \subset X$.

My problem is that this stronger result is never proved, and is only alluded to at the very end of the section (literally in the very last paragraph), as a mere consequence of the weaker result above. However I've tried to prove it using **only** what is given up to that point but have failed. Considering the cursory treatment they gave to it I imagine the proof is a one-liner, but so far I have come empty handed.

**So my question is:** how do you prove this stronger result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a bijection $\varphi$ between $X$ and a natural number $n$.

Now suppose that $\psi$ is a bijection between $X$ and a proper subset $Y$.

$\varphi \circ \psi \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is a bijection between $n$ and a proper subset. A contradiction.

Comment: Fantastic! A one-liner indeed. Thank you.